# I want to add text after the icon like the image above using html5. Any suggestion?

Tags: html, css

I want to add text after the icon using HTML. Any help?
Below is the  image.

[image: Example]

Comment: I do not see an image, but happy to help if you can be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I wrap text around a non rectangular image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129862/how-can-i-wrap-text-around-a-non-rectangular-image)

Comment: Can you see the link..just click on the link and it will take you to the image.

Comment: Hey Bhavya .. Can you please elaborate. I cant able to see any icon in that image

Comment: @Bhavya i guess it would help if you edit this image on where you wnat text and post the html/css code that you currently use to display the image/site.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way to do it, if you do not use any framework like bootstrap, you can try following:

```css
.myContent { margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #ccc; }
.myContent .left { float:left; width:20%;}
.myContent .text { padding:10px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

```html
<div class="myContent">
   <div class="left">
     <img src="images/your-image.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="left">
    <div class="text">
       my text....more text...
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```