How to wrap text completely around a png object using CSS without canvas
I need to wrap text around an object (from a png image) using CSS. The text should be wrapped just like how it is arranged in the attached image, not in a box or a defined shape. I have achieved the same result using python and html canvas, but I am required to do it without canvas (just paragraph tags, spans and divs).
Please note that I have very little experience in front end development and CSS
I found a few solutions that attempt to solve this but none of them could do it completely.
The desired output:

I have solved the problem in python, because that is what I know (I work in AI). I had used pillow library because I need custom fonts in other languages.
The attached image is output of the same program.
I could achieve the same result using Html canvas, but it is not permitted to be used in the problem statement.
I need a flexible solution where the image can be positioned anywhere within the text, not just as a left or right column using shape-outside and floats. The text should maintain its alignment regardless of image placement.
In this solution the desired output is received because the shape is a circle, and this developer has used its radius and position to arrange the text. But in my case, the object will be a real png with random shape.

This answer does exactly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74146506/2691058
